# node.js - Static files CSS / JS not working in express

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, socket.io

I Understand many people have asked the same question but i just can't get this to work for me at all.

I am trying to make a socket.IO application and are following the tutorials but just can't get CSS and JS to be loaded to the page. The application just always sends the html page.

My folder structure.

```
./server.js
./public
    /css
        /styles.css
    /js
        /client.js
    /index.html
```

My Server.js file contains:

```
var express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const server = express()
    .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX) )
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

const io = socketIO(server);
```

And in my index.html file I call the css and js like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />
<script src="/js/client.js"></script>
```

Comment: Go in network tab and look at request status

Comment: how about looking up for the network at chrome devtools?  what's the request url and what's the error

Comment: What errors you get? Are you sure server root is properly set?
have you tried relative path includes? 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script src="js/client.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use two express variables `app` and `server`

Try the following

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var express = require('express');

const app = express()
    .get('/', function (req, res) {res.sendFile(INDEX)})
    .use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

const io = socketIO(app);
```

Comment: How could this work?  This installs a middleware that will call `res.sendFile(INDEX)` for every single route and does not ever call `next()` so the `express.static()` middleware will never get called.

Comment: @jfriend00 made the correction. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Perfect, that works correctly. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const socketIO = require('socket.io')(http);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

http.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```

Your code doesn't work because `.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX))` always sends `index.html`, to any request from the client.